# Error when I import 'videosequence' in Python 3.9

Tags: python

```
import glob
import os
from contextlib import closing
from videosequence import VideoSequence
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition
import subprocess
from pytube import YouTube
```

When I run my project in a venv in Pycharm, this error message shows up

```
C:/Users/usr/PycharmProjects/project/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from videosequence import VideoSequence
  File "C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\videosequence\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Comment: What version of python are you using mabe this link can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/80448/what-would-cause-the-gi-module-to-be-missing-from-python

Comment: @Efa As it says in the title I am using Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

From the [VideoSequence GitHub page](https://github.com/rjw57/videosequence):

> - The implementation is based on GStreamer and so de facto only works on a modern Unix-alike such as Linux or FreeBSD.
> - The PyGObject introspection libraries must be installed. (See below.)

You seem to be working on Windows (I do not know whether VideoSequence does in fact work on Windows), and, crucially, it is clear PyGObject is not installed.

Comment: Your answer says is based on GStreamer, which your comment implies that it doesn't work on Windows, however I managed to install GStreamer. I just don't know how to install PyGObject.

Comment: Not my answer — the VideoSequence README says so, I just quoted it. As for PyGObject, you can find the installation instructions for Windows [here](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started). (Again, I have not tested it, only linking the published docs.) If you manage to make it work, you might want to let the VideoSequence team know to update their documentation.